# WordPress Social Login : Unspecified error. #6 With Twitter

Tags: wordpress

I had recently got this error with Twitter in WordPress Social Login

```
Unspecified error. #6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After googling i got solution, open \wp-content\plugins\wordpress-social-login\hybridauth\Hybrid\Providers\Twitter.php and

```
        $this->api->api_base_url      = "https://api.twitter.com/1/";
```

with

```
    $this->api->api_base_url      = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
```

because twitter abort old API 1 and move to API 1.1.

Comment: YEs @Cek, basically Wordpress Social Login use HybridAuth (http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/) for communicating with all social site, and HybridAuth already update their twitter library.

Comment: And it also seems you need to have your Twitter authentication setup since the v1.1 API requires OAuth even to just get timeline updates.

Comment: new version of wordpress social login comes with twitter api 1.1, still getting **Cannot redeclare class OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1**, this function call again but where don't know..